# How to add some delay between AnimationController.repeat() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, delay, flutter-animation, animationcontroller

I need to add some delay between each iteration of animation gets call to repeat. Something like the following image.
[image]

I tried to do it by passing value to the period parameter of the repeat method but it was not what I expected.

```
_controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: widget.period)
      ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
        if (status != AnimationStatus.completed) {
          return;
        }
        _count++;
        if (widget.loop <= 0) {
          //_controller.repeat(period: Duration(microseconds: 5000));
          _controller.repeat();
        } else if (_count < widget.loop) {
          _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
        }
      });
```

I've also tried to add Tween with the animation. That didn't help either. Can you help me clarify where I went wrong?

```
AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
          parent: _controller,
          curve: Interval(0.5, 1.0)
        ),
      ),
      child: widget.child,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => _Shiner(
        child: child,
        direction: widget.direction,
        gradient: widget.gradient,
        percent: _controller.value,
        enabled: widget.enabled,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: when using status listener call `forward()` inside `Future.delayed()` method callback

Comment: @pskink  you mean this right?

Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 5000),(){
        _controller.forward();
});

But it's didn't work

Comment: well microseconds is really really short period, also you would need `from: 0.0`

Comment: But 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds neh!

Comment: but you used `microseconds: 5000`

Comment: oh goh.. i miss that. Okay all that happens now is to wait 5 seconds for the animation to start and repeat without delay.

Comment: even this not help - Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000),(){
            _controller.repeat();
          });

Comment: so read my todays's first comment again

Comment: Once it is called _controller.repeat () the delay does not add up between the animation

Comment: this is because you call `repeat` - instead you should "repeat" your controller by yourself (with calling `forward` inside `Future.delayed`)

Comment: Thank you very muchhhhhhhhhhhh. I got your point

Comment: It works as I really expected. Thank you very much @pskink for your valuable time. Could you please add your comment as an answer? Then I can set it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) Now it's working as I expected. All you have to do is repeat the controller yourself instead of trying to add delay to controller.repeat()

```
_controller.addStatusListener((status) { 
  if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
   Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 5000),(){
     if(mounted){
       _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
     }
   });
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `if(mounted)`.
Because you have a chance that forwards the disposed of animation controller.

Comment: Man it should be `if(mounted)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `CurvedAnimation` and supplying an appropriate [Interval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Interval-class.html).

1. add the desired delay to the `AnimationController` duration
2. calculate an `Interval` based on the ratio of the delay and total animation duration.
3. create a `CurvedAnimation` and supply the created `Interval`

Below you can find the calculations wrapped into a class for ease of use.

```dart
const delay = Duration(seconds: 5);
_controller = AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1) + delay,
  vsync: this,
)..repeat();
_animation = DelayedCurvedAnimation(
  controller: _controller,
  delayEnd: delay,
);

// Interval calculation and Animation creation

class DelayedCurvedAnimation extends CurvedAnimation {
  DelayedCurvedAnimation({
    required AnimationController controller,
    Duration delayStart = Duration.zero,
    Duration delayEnd = Duration.zero,
    Curve curve = Curves.linear,
  }) : super(
    parent: controller,
    curve: _calcInterval(controller, delayStart, delayEnd, curve),
  );

  static Interval _calcInterval(AnimationController controller, Duration delayStart, Duration delayEnd, Curve curve) {
    final animationStartDelayRatio = delayStart.inMicroseconds / controller.duration!.inMicroseconds;
    final animationEndDelayRatio = delayEnd.inMicroseconds / controller.duration!.inMicroseconds;
    return Interval(animationStartDelayRatio, 1 - animationEndDelayRatio, curve: curve);
  }
}
```

**Example (try it on https://dartpad.dev):**

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const FadeTransitionExampleApp());

class FadeTransitionExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FadeTransitionExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: FadeTransitionExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FadeTransitionExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const FadeTransitionExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<FadeTransitionExample> createState() => _FadeTransitionExampleState();
}

class _FadeTransitionExampleState extends State<FadeTransitionExample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;
  late final Animation<double> _animation;
  
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    const delay = Duration(seconds: 5);
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1) + delay,
      vsync: this,
    )..repeat();
    _animation = DelayedCurvedAnimation(
      controller: _controller,
      delayEnd: delay,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animation,
      child: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: FlutterLogo(),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


class DelayedCurvedAnimation extends CurvedAnimation {
  DelayedCurvedAnimation({
    required AnimationController controller,
    Duration delayStart = Duration.zero,
    Duration delayEnd = Duration.zero,
    Curve curve = Curves.linear,
  }) : super(
    parent: controller,
    curve: _calcInterval(controller, delayStart, delayEnd, curve),
  );

  static Interval _calcInterval(AnimationController controller, Duration delayStart, Duration delayEnd, Curve curve) {
    final animationStartDelayRatio = delayStart.inMicroseconds / controller.duration!.inMicroseconds;
    final animationEndDelayRatio = delayEnd.inMicroseconds / controller.duration!.inMicroseconds;
    return Interval(animationStartDelayRatio, 1 - animationEndDelayRatio, curve: curve);
  }
}
```

**Note:**
For animations running in reverse you may have to do a little bit of extra work.